# Divide by 0 Error in PHP calculator

Tags: php

I have a simple calculator with code shown below.  I have 3 inputs and a simple equation.  But i keep getting a divide by 0 error even before i click the calculate button.  What am I doing wrong here?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['valuea'])) $valuea = $_POST['valuea'];
if (isset($_POST['valueb'])) $valueb = $_POST['valueb'];
if (isset($_POST['valuec'])) $valuec = $_POST['valuec'];
$answer = ($valuea - $valueb) / $valuec;

echo <<<_END
<form method='post' action='/depreciation.php'>
<table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">

<tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>Stright Line Depreciation</strong></td>         </tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Enter Cost:</td><td align="center"><input type='text'     name='valuea' value="$valuea"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow2"><td>End Salvage Value:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='valueb' value="$valueb"/></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Enter Estimated Life:</td><td align="center"><input type='text' name='valuec' value="$valuec"/></td></tr>
<tr class="submit"><td colspan="2"><input type='submit' value='Calculate'/></td></tr>
_END;

?>

<tr class="calcrow">
<td><i>The answer is:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo round($answer)?>"></td></i>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: JavaScript? Where is your JavaScript? Why do you want a calculator in PHP?

Comment: Nothing is stopping your code from executing right away... And your problem is in PHP, not Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

`$answer` is being evaluated on page load, as dc2 commented, nothing is stopping your code from being executed as soon as you load the page...

`$answer = ($valuea - $valueb) / $valuec;`

this produces your error when you load the page.

To avoid this you should check for 0 before you do the division:

```
if($valuec == 0){
    $answer = "TO INFINITY AND BEYOND";
}else{
   //division here
}
```

Comment: right, the code does execute but im looking for a way to get rid of the divide by zero error when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you check in the first three lines of code to see if the $_POST[] variables are set, but then regardless of whether they are or not, you go ahead and assign $answer a value.  So what happens if those values aren't set?

I haven't written PHP in some time, so I may be wrong, but you may want to check $_POST[] for data prior to executing any code whatsoever and if you find nothing has been set, redirect the user to the form that they should have filled out.

Just my $0.02 - let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You could change

```
$answer = ($valuea - $valueb) / $valuec;
```

to

```
if ((isset($valuea))&&(isset($valueb))&&(isset($valuec))){
     $answer = ($valuea - $valueb) / $valuec;
}
```

Then you will avoid the calc with empty values

Answer (score 0):

I'd take advantage of [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) and also test for 0 before dividing like so:

```
<?php
$valuea='';
$valueb='';
$valuec='';
$answer='';

if (isset($_POST['valuea'])) $valuea = $_POST['valuea'];
if (isset($_POST['valueb'])) $valueb = $_POST['valueb'];
if (isset($_POST['valuec'])) $valuec = $_POST['valuec'];
if(is_numeric($valuea) && is_numeric($valueb) && is_numeric($valuec))
{
    if($valuec=='0')
    {
        $answer ="Error: Dividing by zero";
    }
    else{
        $answer = ($valuea - $valueb) / $valuec;
    }
}

echo <<<_END
<form method='post'>
<table border='0' width='500px' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='1' class="table">
<tr class="calcheading"><td colspan="2"><strong>Stright Line Depreciation</strong></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Enter Cost:</td><td align="center"><input type="text" name="valuea" value="$valuea" /></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow2"><td>End Salvage Value:</td><td align="center"><input type="text" name="valueb" value="$valueb" /></td></tr>
<tr class="calcrow"><td>Enter Estimated Life:</td><td align="center"><input type="text" name="valuec" value="$valuec" /></td></tr>
<tr class="submit"><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Calculate" /></td></tr>
_END;

?>
<tr class="calcrow"><td><em>The answer is:</em></td><td align="center"><input type="text" value="<?php echo is_numeric($answer)?round($answer):$answer; ?>"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here's a [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/f2u-cir) and [its results](http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/f2u-cir).